# Generate JSON array

Tags: javascript, php, json, typo3

I want to generate a JSON array with PHP, but it doesn't work well.

My PHP array looks like this:

`protected $resultArray = array("1.0" => 0, "1.3" => 0);`

then I do this:

`return json_encode($resultArray);`

but then i've got this:

`var array = [{&quot;1.0&quot;:2,&quot;1.3&quot;:1}];`

Why is " replaced with `&quot;`?

Comment: Is there a htmlentities() or htmlspecialchars() function somewhere in your code?

Comment: The problem lies elsewhere in your code, not with json_encode. Post more code and we can help.

Comment: where is it being `returned` to before being sent to page?

Comment: I use this as a part of typo3. The function is called from an Typo3 controller. 

and send with this function to my view:

`$this->view->assign('chartarray', $helper->genArray($notes));`

Comment: `return json_encode($resultArray, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);` this also dosn't have any effect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys for help!

The solution is (only for typo3). To get a properly correct JSON-Array in the view the JS code has to be improved the following way:

`var array = {f:format.htmlentitiesDecode(value:chartarray)};`

Answer (score 2):

`quot;` is a quote character (`"`) encoded as HMTL. `json_encode()` does not produce HTML encoded sequences.

Replace `return` with `echo` in `return json_encode($resultArray);` and you'll see this for yourself.

Most probably the returned string is passed further to a function that runs it through `htmlspecialchars()` or `htmlentities()` and this is the correct way to work with it if you put it into an HMTL context.

Use a different viewer class if you need to output only the `json_encode()`-ed string. I don't know TYPO3 but I guess you should use [`JsonView`](https://github.com/TYPO3/TYPO3.CMS/blob/master/typo3/sysext/extbase/Classes/Mvc/View/JsonView.php); pass it `$resultArray` as-is and it will call `json_encode()` for you.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may using etended library for example in wamp server I tested this code and it's work fine

```
   $str = "<div style='position:relative'><img src='/assets/ui/success.png' /><span 
   style='position:relative;top:-15px;'>Nachricht empfangen!</span></div>";

   echo json_encode(array('prompt' => $str));
```

//output

```
//{"prompt":"<div style='position:relative'><img src='\/assets\/ui\/success.png' \/><span   style='position:relative;top:-15px;'>Nachricht empfangen!<\/span><\/div>"}
```

Comment: no that dosn't have any effect, result ist quite the same.

` var array = [{&quot;prompt&quot;:{&quot;1.0&quot;:2,&quot;1.3&quot;:1}]; `

Comment: I repeat it again which you need to change your php library,I said that ,I guess your problem related to you php library which that json_encode included.